How can I specify where the each individual dependency come from using `conan install`?
I am using a GitHub action runner to run some scripts. The goal is to build a dependency from conancenter remote and upload it to my personal specified remote. However, I want to gather the dependencies of this dependency from my personal existing remote, but I need to fetch the conanfile.py from the conancenter remote.
To accomplish this so far I have,
conan remote clean

conan remote add -f my_personal_remote ...
conan remote add conancenter ...

conan install ...

Hence, when I perform a conan install this will search the remote from my specified personal remote, fail and then fetch the conanfile.py from conancenter. Then, it will search again for all of my dependencies, but find them on my personal remote as they exist.
This feels "risky", ideally I want to have something like,
conan install <My dependency to build> -r conancenter (To fetch the conanfile.py)
conan install <The dependency of my dependency to build> -r my_personal_remote


Using conan download with the --recipe flag to download only the recipe and then conan install with --build=<dependency> to utilize the recipe and specify the remote as conan install -r ... seems to accomplish what I want.

In the general case it would be recommended to build the packages directly from the conan-center-index repo, check https://docs.conan.io/2/devops/using_conancenter.html. This way you also have full control, can do customizations, etc. Furthermore, with the new "local-recipes-index" repo type (https://blog.conan.io/2024/04/23/Introducing-local-recipes-index-remote.html) you can do this very easily.

For questions about these features, the Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues can be used for questions too and official responses and support from the maintainers.
